# Is it possible to create a self-installing PHP framework?

Tags: php, file, installation

Ok this might seems a bad idea or an obvious one. But let's imagine a CMS like PHPBB. And let's imagine you'd build one. I'd create just 1 file called PHPBB.install.php and running it it will create all folders and files needed with PHP. I mean, the user run it just once and every file and folder of the app is created via the PHP file.

**Why to do this?**

Well mostly because it's cleaner and you are pretty much sure it creates everything as you wish (obliviously checking everything about the server first). Also, having all the files backed-up inside a file you would be able to restore it very easily by deleting everything and reinstalling it running again PHPBB.install.php. Backing-up files like this will allow you to also prevent errors: How? When an error occurred in a file, this file is restored as it was and automatically re-run.

**It would be too heavy!**

The installation would happen only once and you'd be sure the user will not forget to place the files correctly. The error-preventing will worth the cause and it would also happen only once.

Now the questions:

1. Does this technique exists? If so, What's its name?
2. Why would you discourage it?

Comment: "has it a name?"  Isn't it an "installer"?  Indeed, how is this different from an "installer"?

Comment: @S.Lott, It creates the file structure too.

Comment: How is what you want different than a .zip file or the likes?

Comment: @Charliepiga: How is that different from an installer?  All the installers I've ever run create file structures.  How is this different?  Why ask for a new word when "installer" seems to be what you're describing?

Comment: Seriously? "It's not a question" vote to close is just disappointing me so much... This question has even a paragraph that starts with "Now the questions:"

Comment: @Zirak, The ZIP file is files and folders already made that you move to the root. I mean that one PHP file creates every other files with `fopen()` and stuff like this...

Comment: @S.Lott, every installer? Which one? Not surely the PHPBB one...

Comment: In the FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."  This question is a hypothetical and should be closed.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Further, the FAQ also says: If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

Comment: @Stephen, I'm starting a project and I was wondering if this method would be ok. It's pratical, answerable and based on actual problem I face...

Comment: @Charliepiga see comment #2.  The fundamental essence of this question is "What are the merits of this idea."  If you instead were to write a program that tried to do what you want, and it was failing, then you would have a valid reason to ask about a specific programming problem.

Comment: @Stephen, I said that it is a pratical problem I'm facing...no discussion intent...

Comment: @Charliepiga, then I ask:  What have you tried?

Comment: @Stephen, I'm looking for a suggestion. I'm not asking for script or anything like this. There are many approved questions out there that start with "should I or should I not" do this without any code...

Comment: @Charliepiga: How is that different from an installer? **All** the installers I've ever run create file structures.  Every single one.  Every .MSI installer.  Every Mac OS X installer.  Every Linux installer.  Every single one creates files.  How is this different?  Please **update** the question to specify very clearly how this is different from every other installer.

Comment: @S.Lott, I think I have seen also installers that either (a) do not create file structures (e.g., they create DB stuff instead) or (b) do much more than just create file structures.

Comment: @S. Lott: Did you realized that we are talking about PHP and web?

Comment: @binaryLV: While true, I can't understand what part of the question is different from an ordinary installer.  I've downloaded installers from web sites since the '90's.  This sounds like a plain-old installer to me.

Comment: @Charliepiga: Please **update** the question to explain how this is not a simple installer that's simply downloaded from a PHP page that simply installs files on the local PC.  I still can't see anything unique or different.  Please **update** the question to contain all the unique, different and interesting features of this project.  Please don't add a lot of comments.  Please **update** the question to be complete and clear.

Comment: @S.Lott, Webly (from "web") speaking it's not that usual. In fact, knowing a lot of CMS and other script I've never saw anyone or anybody applying this installer. It's also because probably PHP is not ready (that's why I asked the question) for this, and also because there are a lot of server types all around the world and it's not that sure that everyone will allow you to use functions `fopen()` to manage files. If you are that sure that "webly" speaking it's not that unique: find out I'm wrong, find out one PHP installer that acts as I wrote.

Comment: @Charliepiga: What's do you mean by a PHP installer?  A PHP page that downloads an installer?  Aren't almost all downloads offered by PHP pages?   It's very hard to tell if a site is PHP powered, but any site that's PHP powered and downloads an MSI would be a PHP Installer.  Right?  If not, please **update** the question to clearly define "PHP installer" if it's not a PHP-powered website that downloads an installer.

Comment: @S.Lott, there is a huge difference between "MSI installer that is downloaded from PHP-powered web page" and "PHP powered installer", i.e., single PHP script/file that would "install" some PHP system. As I wrote, I'd advise to read about `__halt_compiler()` which is meant for such "installers".

Comment: @binaryLV.  "there is a huge difference"?  What is the difference?  Can you convince @Charliepiga to **update** the question to define that difference?

Comment: The difference is that in one case it is *setup.msi*, *setup.exe* or something like that (executable program, meant to be run on some operating system, e.g., msi and exe - on windows), in other case it's *setup.php* (script file that needs to be parsed/executed by PHP).

Comment: Another difference is that while msi and exe installers are quite common in the world of software, php installers are very rare.

Comment: @S.Lott, You really want me to ***update*** my question, eh? :) You might come from a "real" programming world, where installers are every days things, but here, in the PHP pseudo-programming world, these things are yet to come. And for a PHP pseudo-programmer it's quite strange to ear about installers for the reasons listed below in the accepted answer.

Comment: @Charliepiga: I still don't understand the question.  It's hard to follow all the comments.  I don't see how the answer is acceptable.  I'm asking for one thing.  Please **clarify** the question to explain more fully.  Please don't add yet more hard-to-follow comments.  Please **clarify** the question by **updating** it to explain what it is you're talking about.

Comment: @S.Lott, Well, I think it's quite answerable and I am satisfied by the answer, so I don't really see what's the problem. I don't know how to make it easier to understand. Anyway, if you think this question is not good, flag it and vote it to close. Over :)

Comment: @Charliepiga: "I don't know how to make it easier to understand"  I think you could explain more clearly what you want.  I think you could provide an example, or a sequence of actions or a scenario or a use case that explains it.  I think you could describe what a user sees and does and what the "system" (browser? server?) does.  I think you could describe what you expect to happen.  You clearly have something in mind.  You could describe that something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As others have said, an installer.
2. It requires the web server to have permission to write to the filesystem, and ends up having the files owned by the user the web server runs as. Even when one has the ability to change filesystem permissions, it's usually a longer process than just extracting an archive and having the initial setup verify permissions.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this technique exists? If so, What's its name?

I'd advise to read about [`__halt_compiler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.halt-compiler.php). It allows you to mix PHP code with non-php data which is not parsed, so you may have PHP code ("installer") and binary data (e.g., compressed contents of all the files) in single PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Yes, there is a single install file in PHPBB.  You run through an online wizard defining your settings and then it installs automatically.

http://www.phpbb.com/support/documents.php?mode=install&version=3&sid=908f5766fc04868ccb985c1b1e6dee4b#quickinstall

2 - The only reason to discourage it would be if you want the user to understand exactly how the system works.  Automatically installing it means the user has no need to understand the nitty gritty of it all - of course, many see this as a good thing.

Comment: But it does not create the file structure. It just create the database schema.

Comment: Well the file structure is just copied over anyway.  I guess it wouldn't be too difficult to have the install script unzip it for you, but I don't see why it's necessary considering it's just a copy and paste job.

Comment: Well maybe, but in PHPBB you need to have already unzipped everything to run the install script in the first place.

Comment: @Nick Brunt. You might misunderstood me. I mean that from the PHPBB site you'd  download just one file called PHPBB.installer.php and running it it will (with `fopen()` and similar functions) create the file structure writing the files. No folders, no zip, nothing.

Comment: That would be incredibly difficult to write... Unless the file itself includes the zipped document structure like an exe installer on Windows.

Comment: @Nick Brunt. Exactly. Like an exe. You'd create the CMS and then copy all the scripts in string that would be extracted after.

Comment: `__halt_compiler()` allows to make something similar to Windows single-file .exe installers. Does not seem to be anything difficult.